# make a table with one title and three or two columns

Tags: html, html-table, alignment

I want to make a table that have only one title at the center and two or three columns as of this picture. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IDfBI09c5Oo4HYJKTmIb5LY97HFVfJLr

I tried the following to complete table as shown in picture above but it is not being properly aligned exactly as of picture.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>some textt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `colspan=2` to make the `th` cell span two columns.

Add a bit of css to format the table as desired

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
tr,td{border:1px solid #aaa;}
td,th{text-align:center;padding:5px 10px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>some textt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

#### Updated

To show centering of table header.

Also note that `<table>` is 1990s tech. A much better replacement has been recently introduced: CSS Grid. CSS Grid uses DIV structures instead of tables, and new CSS3 instructions that format the divs into table structures. It is MUCH more flexible than the old `<table></table>` structure, and, frankly, easier *(once the table has become complex)*. References:

[W3Schools basic intro](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

[CSSTricks Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

[GridByExample](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/)
NB: this final one by the editor of the excellent [SmashingMagazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/04/best-practices-grid-layout/)

Comment: table's title is not being centered properly, i think other factors are affecting please have a look https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oH1qYyjOQ81uHotZUeT02slk4W9yQrKw @cssyphus sir and there is nothing in ste.css linked there. I'm trying to do that till you suggest me answer, please help me to fix that and keep table inside accordion.

Comment: Notice in the css section (first section), the instruction `text-align:center` is beside the `td` selector. Thus, it is centered for the `td` cells.  If you also want it centered for the `th` cells, you can change the selector from `td` to `td, th`, like this: **`td, th{text-align:center;padding:5px 10px;}`** *Above answer updated to do this*

Comment: Also note that TABLEs are 1990s tech. A much better replacement has been recently introduced: CSS Grid.  CSS Grid uses DIV structures instead of tables, and new CSS3 instructions that format the divs into table structures. It is MUCH more flexible than the old table structure, and, frankly, easier (once the table has become complex).  See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) and [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and [this](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/) (the final one by the editor of SmashingMagazine

Answer (score 0):

Added `colspan` the html `attribute` for `table` tag, please following of the code.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```